# Working with enumerations marked with Flag Attribute in the PropertyGrid

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, enums, propertygrid

I have an enumeration marked with a Flag attribute. How can I establish convenient editing property with type of this enumeration in the PropertyGrid? I should be able to set such values as enumValue1 | enumValue2. Also, customized strings for this enum values should be displayed in the PropertyGrid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inherits PropertyGrid & override methods...

Comment: Types Converter is helpful
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/customizingcollectiondata.aspx